# SwiftMessages Exec Bad Access using SwiftMessages.defaultConfig

Tags: swift, swiftmessages

I try to use `SwiftMessages` into my Swift iOS project.

`SwiftMessages` has been installed with `pod` in version 6.0

When I use a sample code like this :

```
    let error = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .cardView)
    error.configureTheme(.error)
    error.configureContent(title: "Error", body: "Something is horribly wrong!")
    error.button?.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
    SwiftMessages.show(view: error)
```

Until now, it's ok !

But when I try to use `SwiftMessages.Config()` or `SwiftMessages.defaultConfig` like this :

```
    let warning = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .cardView)
    warning.configureTheme(.warning)
    warning.configureDropShadow()

    let iconText = ["", "", "", ""].sm_random()!
    warning.configureContent(title: "Warning", body: "Consider yourself warned.", iconText: iconText)
    warning.button?.isHidden = true
    var warningConfig = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
    warningConfig.presentationStyle = .top
    //warningConfig.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindow.Level.statusBar)
    SwiftMessages.show(config: warningConfig, view: warning)
```

I obtain an Exec Bad Access on the `SwiftMessages.show(config: warningConfig, view: warning)`

More over, it does not recognize the property `presentationContext`, that's why the line is in comment in my code. However this property is listed here : https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages

So, is there something wrong in my code, or is there a bug inside the framework ?

Comment: Looks like you have some derived data related to newest version of pod. Try to clean up derived data or implicitly specify pod namespace before calling config func.

Comment: I already tried to clean my project and derived data without any success.

Comment: Try pod install without SwiftyMessage pod and then within

Comment: Thanks for your help, finally as suggesting by @Timothy it was a problem with compatibility Swift's version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your app is on Swift 4.1 or lower. The Swift compatibility is as follows:

- Swift 4.2 -> SwiftMessages 6
- Swift 4.1 or lower -> SwiftMessages 5

Comment: After setting Swift compiler to 4.2 it works fine, thanks for your answer.